# Python -- I have a b dictionary made of functions (key and value), how to grab only the arg of the value (and not the result of the function)

Tags: python, function, dictionary, key-value

As an example:

```py
my_dict = {func1(a, b) : func2(**c**, d), func1(e, f) : fonc2(g, h), etc}
```

if I only want to grab the value (arg) of **c** from my dictionary, what would be the easiest way?

Comment: Just by accessing `c` from the scope where `my_dict` was declared? e.g. `print(c)` after `my_dict` was declared.  Otherwise I am not sure what exactly you are after, more details are needed as you are being unclear with what you are trying to achieve or what exact problems you are trying to solve.

Comment: yes just accessing c..
my_dict = {func1(1, 2) : func2("cat", "bird"), func1(8, 12) : fonc2("monkey", "snake"), etc}

I want to print the first arg of the value from my first key (which would be "cat")...

Comment: "I have a dictionary made of functions" No you don't. You have a dictionary that has *the result of calling functions*, not the functions themselves

Comment: you're right @juanpa.arrivillaga .. i'm quite new to programming

Comment: [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)... [Formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Comment: Maybe if it can helps (to help me)... it's not like i can access the dictionary directly: i'm working through classes and methods. I'm calling a class which contain itself a dictionary, which is made of function's result. However, I'm not sure how I can be more clever than my example (please tell me what is missing). What i'm interested to grab, is the args inside the value function. Is it something even feasible?

Comment: Right now, my solution is to create a method right into the class which return the result of the function back to the args. Kind of sketchy i guess.. but at least it works... Should be a better way...

Answer (score 0):

From what I can understand from this question,
First, you have to find the value where this c lies. Once you have the function you can use the inspect function in python to get all the arguments of this function

`print(inspect.getargspec(func2))`

Comment: ok seems a good path to follow. I know the key, but I'm not sure how to move from there to the inspect function. 
mydict.get(func1(1,2)) will give me the value (based on the result of its function)